# Paypal subscription modify questions

Tags: paypal, custom-fields, subscription

Now i use Paypal subscription button to get the payment,and my customer can modify his(or her)subscription.But there has a problem, my customer could only modify the order amount,and couldn't modify the custom fields(the information of customer apply to me) .Is there a way that my customer can modify the custom  fields,thanks advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  You'd have to kill that subscription and setup a new one.

If you switch to the Recurring Payments API instead of using Standard Subscriptions you'd have more freedom to update things via the UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile API.